# is it possible to have a uidatepicker say "tomorrow" like it does with "today"?

Tags: swift, swift3, uidatepicker

I have a label which takes a relative formatted date so it automatically converts today and tomorrow to "Today"/"Tomorrow". I know the UIDatePicker has a "Today" but is there any way I can also get it to say "Tomorrow"?

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not something that you can edit. You can change overall text color or font but not the text. If you really want to have a tomorrow there, you can use a `UIPickerView` and implement all the texts if that worth the efforts.